# Error in Joomla Site

Tags: joomla, warnings, joomla1.5

I just noticed an error in my Joomla site which says:

```
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in /home/yucoke/public_html/administrator/components/com_content/helper.php on line 115
```

and

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/yucoke/public_html/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php on line 68
```

I am using Joomla 1.5.15 and this happened after my hosting control panel was upgraded not sure though if it's the only reason for the error. Also I have noticed I can't view my menus and can't filter and or search in the Joomla backend. Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling this could be solved by updating you website to the latest version of the 1.5 series (1.5.26). You will have to download the 1.5.0 - 1.5.26 update as this is all the Joomla site provide now.

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=6311

Sometime, these type of error occur when there is something wrong with 3rd party extensions, however, if you're saying this occurred after a control panel update, I can't see how a 3rd party extensions could be causing this.

Hope this helps.